# Inserting Binary data into an access db using oledb

Tags: c#

The following Code throws an error:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images ([Album Image]) VALUES ( @Data)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", data);// data is byte[]
    i=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// throws error . . . System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in
```

also tried the following with the same results:

```
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images ([Album Image]) Values (@Picture)";
    OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@Picture";
    parameter.DbType = DbType.Binary;
    cm.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

```
type here
```

Comment: Post the actual full exception and the table definition. `Data type mismatch in` probably means you passed the wrong data. The full error contains more information.

Comment: In the second example there is no value for the parameter @picture. Did you forget to add it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Access is not a real database engine, and there are tons of potential problems with max size, compactation, performance, etc. I would recommend a real database, possibly embedded like SQLite. Or just store images as files, possibly in an archive.

Comment: the data I passed is a byte[] and I originally had parameter.Value = data but it got removed somewhere along the way

Answer (score 0):

just set the data type for your data

```cs
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Images ([Album Image]) VALUES (@Data)", connection))
{
      // Assuming 'data' is a byte[] containing your binary data
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", OleDbType.Binary).Value = data;
      int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

## Edit 1

alter col "Album Image" in images table to be binrary data type

Comment: I tried this originally with the same results

Comment: @mmarshall you will need to update your table to have the row as binary data, see the answer update

Comment: Album Image is type Binary

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
An Access binary field is limited to just over 500 bytes but I was trying to insert >200K bytes;
I changed the field type to Ole Object and this code works (note data is a byte[] and OleDbType is Binary):

```
OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand();
cm.Connection = cn;
cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images ([Album Image]) Values (@Data)";
cm.Parameters.Add("@Data", OleDbType.Binary).Value = data;
i = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```